# How can I replace normal pointer with shared pointer without changing existing function syntax

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, boost, shared-ptr

Conceder below c++ code.

```
class BaseData { ....}     
class AppData: public BaseData {
...
}
notifyData(BaseData*){...}
// Thread 1  
sendData()
{  
BaseData *adata = new AppData();
notifyData(adata);  
}


// Thread 2    
RecvData( BaseData *adata ){  

...   
delete adata;   
}
```

Just assume that there is different code (not specified above) which manages getting data send using notifyData and make that available to Thread 2 and RecvData function.

Now I want to use boost shared pointers so that I don't need to free memory (allocated to AppData object in Thread 1) in Thread 2. Could anyone suggest how can I achieve this?

**Please note that both notifyData and RecvData are part of our internal libraries and can not be changed to accomodate shared pointer.**

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0):

In the scenario you described - in which threads communicate the raw pointers to each other, you can't use shared pointer as such - since you have code accessing the pointed-to data while not holding a shared pointer. Just imagine what would happen if thread 1 were to exit the context with the shared pointer before thread 2 has received it: The memory would be freed and you'd get a segmentation violation.

If you are sure shared pointers are what you need (and that's not obvious from your question), I would reconsider whether you are actually right in expecting to use your internal libraries here. With this API they are more likely than not to just copy the `BaseData` they got; and even if they don't do that, they inherently assume the memory does not get de-allocated while they're using the pointer.